# DataView Sort - C#/ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the DataView.Sort to sort a column in the dataset. By default, does this assume the data is of type string when it does a sort. If so, how do I make it be datatype aware?

**EDIT: How does it infer the datatype? I am creating a dataset from scratch**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Sort` will honor the datatype of the column.  Now, if you've already converted the column to a string type for display you have a problem.  But if it's still a datetime then you're okay.

Comment: How does it infer the datatype? I am creating a dataset from scratch

Comment: You set the DataType property for each column in each table's .Columns collection.